# Inquiry about Validation Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation

I have a question about Laravel validation. I have two number `<input>` fields like:
[image]

I want to create a rule in the "Request" file from App\Requests\MyRequest.php that requires the value from the second input field to be greater than the first input field and that both fields must have a value greater than 0.

How should I code this? Does Laravel validation support this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add validations in `app/Http/Requests` by running `php artisan make:request MyRequest` something like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class MyRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
       return true;
     }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             'first_field' => 'min:0',
             'second_field' => 'min:'.$this->first_field,
        ];
   }
}
```

You can find more about validations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-min)

Comment: i get it. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: I also have a proplem.I use  'dn_code' => 'unique:user,dn_code' from Request, but 'dn_code' is not fields that i input. I use  my some sentences and syntax from others to create it from App\http\Controller.php. How should we check error 'dn_code' if we don't input (do not a $request). Thank you

Comment: You can write custom validation code to handle that check out here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules where you can validate that field